# Position Fixed Not Working for Header

Tags: css, position, css-position

I am trying to create a very simple effect where the navigation sticks to the top of the page as you scroll down the page. All I should have to do is set "position: fixed" to the header, which I currently have. For some reason, it's treating it more like a "position: absolute" element vs. fixed. I tried it on other elements on the page with the same effect, so I must have something that in my HTML or CSS code that is causing the issue. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/apautler/yDhXG/1/embedded/result/

Header CSS

```
.nav-main  {overflow: visible; position: fixed;
            top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 60px; width: 100%;}
```

*Note, the site is responsive, so the `position: fixed` kicks in at 768px.*

Comment: Hmm. I just tried it in Firefox and it worked. Very strange. It still doesn't work for me in Safari or Chrome even after clearing the browser. Does it work for both of you in webkit browsers? Any idea what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Not working for me, chrome v24.

Comment: I see the problem: Chrome 24

Answer (score 151, accepted):

At the moment, [Chrome cannot render `position:fixed` on elements under a transformation](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574). Delete the (content-free)

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

and it [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/phihag/yDhXG/2/embedded/result/).

Comment: You'll also find that `animation-fill-mode: both` on a/the parent container will stop `position: fixed` from working

Comment: `will-change: transform;` also messes with `position: fixed;` elements.