# Position: fixed nav does not stay fixed

Tags: css, position, background-image, fixed

I have been having a tonne of issues with a site I'm developing. Even download to slow page loads and such. But the biggest issue I'm having is the behaviour of fixed position elements.

First of all the nav is supposed to stay fixed at all times, but it doens't. It does however appear in the middle of the page if you reload whilst you are scrolled. Very odd.

[Live site here](http://www.francesca-designed.me/smm/)

Second of all the background is supposed to stay fixed yet it does not.

Nav code

```
<div class="navwrapper">
    <nav id="top">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#project" class="scroll">The Project</a></li>
                <li><a href="#makers" class="scroll">The Makers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#markets" class="scroll">The Markets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#workshops" class="scroll">The Workshops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#shop" class="scroll">The Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#getinvolved" class="scroll">Get involved</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div></nav>
    <span class="navshadow"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navwrapper{position:fixed;width: 100%;top: 0;}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, no idea what is causing this, but when you remove the `z-index:-1` from your `.label` everything is working. (add `z-index` to your `.navwrapper`, so everything still looks the same).

Comment: @darthmaim thanks, what an odd one. Seems that is should've worked as it was but your solution worked!

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in Chrome with position fixed and transforms:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574

So you will have to remove the transforms from `.label`.

See also:

[Position Fixed Not Working for Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732403/position-fixed-not-working-for-header)