# Position fixed not working on Tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm trying to make a div `position:fixed;`but it's not working at all.

Here's the code:

```
position: fixed;
top: 16px;
left: 16px;
width: 120px;
z-index: 19999;
```

It's a Tumblr Blog, so my guess is that some script / iframe / animation library is breaking something somehow, but I cannot figure it out.

Here's the blog link: [Pale Jane on Tumblr](http://palejane.com/)

I've put a little test div give on the left site of the page. My blog is **nsfw**, so keep minors away if opening it. Sorry, but I just can't recreate it on codepen etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you will have to remove the transforms on your body CSS rule.

I tested this and it works fine. Do you really need transform on the body??

Here is another SO post that suggested it.

[Position: fixed nav does not stay fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758652/position-fixed-nav-does-not-stay-fixed)

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!